# How to add a table to a cell within a table in a word document using the Python module DOCX

Tags: python, docx

I am trying to add a table with 12 rows and 5 columns to a word document that already contains a table. I am trying to do this using the Python DOCX module. See my code below:-

```
import docx
from docx import Document

wordDoc = Document('RNUltraAPEX.docx')
wordDoc_a = Document()
wordTable = wordDoc.tables
numOfTableRows = len(arrayOfItems)

tableToAdd = wordDoc_a.add_table(rows=12, cols=5)
tableToAdd.style = 'Table Grid'
wordTable[0].columns[2].cells[22].value = tableToAdd

wordDoc.save('generatedRN.docx')
```

When I open the generatedRN.docx document though the table does not exist. Could somebody help me please?

Comment: I want to ask for the same question. how to insert an inter table into a table's cell? Have you solved this issue?